# jQuery, cycle error: $("ul#slides").cycle is not a function [Bei diesem Fehler anhalten] next: '#next',

Tags: jquery, function, web, cycle

I get the following error `$("ul#slides").cycle is not a function` in my code.
I am a newbie, so I have no idea of JS neither from jQuery so if anybody can help me could be great.

Here are my codes:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("ul#slides").cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        pause: 1,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
    });
    $("#slideshow").hover(function () {
        $("ul#nav").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $("ul#nav").fadeOut();
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="prev"><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
        <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="slides">
        <li><img src="Images/01.png" alt="Harley Davidson Sportster" /></li>
        <li><img src="Images/02.jpg" alt="Harley Davidson Sportster" /></li>
        <li><img src="Images/03.jpg" alt="Harley Davidson Sportster" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank for the help.

Comment: Have you actually included the cycle plugin?

Comment: This means your plugin is not found. Have you included it in the page?

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the versions of jquery that you are including and make sure you don't have any conflicts.    Often when I've seen this problem it is a result of plugins that require different jquery libraries and the order that they are referenced cause headaches.    Try commenting out any jquery libraries that are not required for the function (including any in master pages)  and see if it still has the error.   If so then make a small bare bones sample html page with just this functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking to more than one JQuery library it's probably conflicting. I am using the cycle plugin w/ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js and it's working well w/ all of my .js scripts.